# Is there an assert test to ensure a page is over SSL?

Tags: casperjs

How would I test that my form is submitting to a secured page. Like `assertHttpStatus()`? Is there a function that can return the protocol of a returned page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken (almost straight) from [the docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/1.1-beta1/modules/tester.html), assertUrlMatch would seem to be the correct choice;

```
casper.test.begin('assertUrlMatch() tests', 1, function(test) {
    casper.start('https://www.google.com/', function() {
        test.assertUrlMatch(/^https:\/\//, 'google.com is served in https://');
    }).run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Comment: This assert does even correctly fail when there is a redirect to the http page. Keep in mind that this assert can only be called when the final page has at least began loading. It should not be used in the `waitForResource` callback.